# WCF Workflow Service: passing multiple parameters

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.5, workflow-foundation

I created WCF Workflow Service and specified some parameters for the Content property of my  Receive activity. API signature for the Service Reference in the client application looks like this:

```
    var client = new ServiceClient();
    var id = client.NewTicket(new NewTicket { 
        firstName = "John", 
        lastName="Doe" 
    });
```

instead of desired:

```
   client.NewTicket("John", "Doe");
```

Can I get rid of this argument wrapping class anyhow while passing multiple parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WriteLine wf1 = new WriteLine();
    Dictionary<String, Object> arg = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
    arg.Add("Text", "Hello,world!");
    WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wf1, arg);
}
```